# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: java, android, exceção, nullpointerexception

Meu programa deu esse problema quando tentei criar uma pilha (banco de dados), para armazenar *strings* no meu app Android

package com.project.meuapp2;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn;
    private EditText texto;
    BancodeDados DB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
        texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.texto);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        texto.setText("Insira um dado");
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String y = texto.getText().toString();
                DB.InsereInicio(y);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        Intent i = null;

        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mnTela1:
                i = new Intent(this, pagina2.class);
                Toast.makeText(this, "item1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.mnTela2:
                Toast.makeText(this, "item2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

package com.project.meuapp2;

```
public class BancodeDados {
    elemento primeiro = new elemento();
    elemento ultimo = new elemento();

    public void InsereInicio(String x){
        elemento novodadoinicio = new elemento();
        novodadoinicio.dado = x;
        novodadoinicio.proximo = primeiro;
        if(primeiro==null){
            ultimo = novodadoinicio;
        }
        primeiro = novodadoinicio;
    }

    public void InsereFinal(String x){
        elemento novodadoultimo = new elemento();
        novodadoultimo.dado = x;
        novodadoultimo.proximo = primeiro;
        if(ultimo==null){
            primeiro = novodadoultimo;
        }
        ultimo = novodadoultimo;
    }

    public String removeInicio(){
        String x;
        x = primeiro.dado;
        primeiro = primeiro.proximo;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Log do Android Studio

> 03-27 18:14:28.017 5239-5239/com.project.meuapp2 E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      Process: com.project.meuapp2, PID: 5239
>                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.project.meuapp2.BancodeDados.InsereInicio(java.lang.String)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                          at com.project.meuapp2.Principal$1.onClick(Principal.java:30)
>                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Nota: Já tentei inicializar a variável `primeiro`, só que acusa o mesmo erro.

Comment: Significa que seu método está recebendo null, tente depurar o código e ver porque isso tá acontecendo.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e ajudar a todos entender isso. Também pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

Possivelmente isto resolve o problema específico (ainda pode ter outros):

```
public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn;
    private EditText texto;
    BancodeDados DB = new BancodeDados(); // <===================== aqui
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/NullPointerException.java).

Você precisa ter uma instância criada para poder acessar seus membros. Só declarar a variável não adianta. Inicializar resolve esta exceção mas pode ser que a instância precisa ser configura apropriadamente para funcionar como desejado.

Comment: ola obrigado,deu ate certo so que como você previu deu outro problema,ele conseguiu inserir os dados corretamente,so que quando fui retirar os dados da pilha em outra Activity,ele deu NullPointerException denovo(pois eu acho que os meus dados inseridos foram apagados quando eu fui para outra activity),oque eu devo fazer para manter os dados inseridos indepedente da activity que eu esteja?